# Need a formula to calculate rating, based on 3 factors?

Tags: analysis

I have multiple users.... millions actually, each user has two values: "Talk About Theft" and "Stole Something".

"Talk About Theft" - 1 to Infinity

"Success Rate" - 0 to Infinity

I need to have some sort of risk rate (1-10) for each user based on the time they were were heard "Talk About Theft", and based on the amount of time they "Stole Something".

The "Talk About Theft" value for a user will generally stand at around 10000(but can grow to infinity), and the "Stole Something" will generally stand at around 5ish (but can grow to infinity)

I would like to "Talk About Theft" value to have a 20% impact on the rating, and the "Stole Something" to have a 40% impact on the rating. Their comparison with the rest of the userbase should have a weighing of 40%

I am assessing risk, however, please note that i am not talking about actual theft related things, it is just an example.

Can anyone help me with some sort of formula to work back to a rating of 1-10?

Comment: This needs a better title.

Comment: Updated the title - i hope it is better now

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches-you need to think about what you want.  One is for each user to count their fractional position in the "Talk about Theft" ranking and scale it to $0$ to $2$.  So if I am higher than $90\%$ of the people, I get $1.8$ points from this.  Do the same for the others on a scale $0-4$.  If I am above $35\%$ of the users on "Stole Something" I get $1.4$ from this.  I don't know what you mean by comparison with the rest of the database means.  Add them up.  This gives you a ranking from $0-10$ with the compositions you asked for.  If you insist on $1-10$, multiply by $0.9$ and add $1$.  This has the advantage of being reasonably impervious to changes in scale of your users.

Comment: in other words, you suggest i compare them  only against the rest of the userbase?

Comment: That is right.  I was suggesting that because it didn't like you had a good scaling.  If one person has a score of 50 and another has a score of 1000, is the second really 20 times more risky?  This lets you ignore the raw scores and just use the ranking.  One way to think about it is that you could take the log of everybody's score.  It would change ratios and intervals between people, but not change the order.  The score I am proposing would not be affected at all.